# Why I get undefined by calling useStore from Vuex? Composition API, Vuex and Typescript in Quasar

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I invoke `useStore` in *setup* hook, then, I get `undefined` which results in *TypeError* when I try to use some *store* functionality.

App.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
    const obtenerAppInitInfo = () => store.dispatch('App/obtenerAppInitInfo')
    console.log(store) // displays undefined
    onMounted(async () => {
      await obtenerAppInitInfo() // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')
    })
    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

Same logic in Options API works fine. Anyone knows why I get `undefined` by calling `useStore`?

Comment: Did you install the plugin? I.e. `createApp(…).use(store)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue relates when using **Vuex and Typescript** in Quasar(v2).

In their documentation, they say:

> If you choose to use Vuex and TypeScript when you create a project folder with **Quasar CLI**, it will add some typing code in src/store/index.ts. To get a typed Vuex store in your component you will need to modify your Vue file like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

// Import the typed store offered by quasar. We no longer import it from vuex.
import { useStore } from 'src/store';

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
  }
})
</script>
```

This has solved my problem. I'd like to mention that this way we get store types inside components, which is great.